# Apple Reporter: transaction id to paid price report

Tags: apple-reporter

When user does in-app purchase in iOS app, we receive transaction id, article id, etc, but we don't receive information how much did he pay. We would like to receive this information somehow.
We tried to use Reporter.jar. We can download sales summary report like this:

```
java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Robot.XML Sales.getReport XXXXXXX, Sales, Summary, Daily, YYYYMMDD
```

But when we try to get sales detailed report (where I hope to see transaction ids listed):

```
java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Robot.XML Sales.getReport XXXXXXXX, Sales, Detailed, Daily, YYYYMMDD
```

we receive error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Error>
    <Code>200</Code>
    <Message>Invalid vendor number specified. Try again.</Message>
</Error>
```

I also don't see transaction ids in Finance report.

**Is there a way to get some apple report from which we can understand how much money were paid in which transaction ?**

*PS. Google provides this information in daily and monthly reports. I hope that Apple also gives it in some report...*

Answer (score 0):

Based on apple's documentation, the transaction-level sale report is only available for certain types, e.g. music/movies/TV, not in-app subscriptions: https://help.apple.com/itc/contentreporterguide/en.lproj/static.html#itc7e183be3b. Instead, you could download the transaction-level report for subscriptions using `Subscriber` as the data type:

```
java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Robot.XML Sales.getReport XXXXXXXX, Subscriber, Detailed, Daily, YYYYMMDD, 1_2
```

Comment: Thank you,
I have tried it, but unfortunatelly there are no transaction ids in this report.

So far, the only possibility to get this information I see in app store connect: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04012020a
I didn't have the chance to try it yet.